# How can I create bar chart that shows the true and false values on every unique hash in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Good day! I'm trying to create a bar-chart in pandas that counts the True and False values (on converted column) on every unique session_hash. How can I do this I'm very new to matplotlib so please help me out.

Dataframe:

```
df = {
'photo_resize': [True, True, True, True, True], 
'session_hash': ['++Dd0Z0ds6EB94ZUff', '++Dd0Z0ds6EB94ZUff', 'UdGx66q45ptTAsFe', 'UdGx66q45ptTAsFe', 'zzWI/4MqjMnI'], 
'converted': [True, True, False, False, True]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
pd.crosstab(df['converted'], df['session_hash']).plot.bar()
```

Comment: Thanks jezreal! However, its not what im looking for i want 2 bars (True and false)
see image: https://imgur.com/a/G5yLHe6

Comment: Yeah the picture is the expected output :)

Comment: @SamuëlW.R - OK, because `on every unique session_hash.` answer was edited

Comment: @SamuëlW.R - swapped columns